# Angular ui-grid sorting is not working when headerCellTemplate is used

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid stable version. When I use custom headerCellTemplate in my gridOptions, my sorting is not working. Besides that, if I use headerCellTemplate, grid header column menu is also not showing. If any one having any example of using headerCellTemplate along with sorting, can you please share? Does stable version of ui-grid has all the functionalities in previous ng-grid stable?

Thanks & Regards,
Jewel Jose.

Answer (score 0):

ui-grid has most of the ng-grid functions, and quite a few extra.  There are some elements that are different, so for example filtering works on the column level not the whole grid at once, but that's different rather than missing.

The most likely reason a custom headerCellTemplate would break things is if you left out things that were in the standard headerCellTemplate.  So if you leave ou the menus, then there won't be menus.  If you leave out the click handlers, then the columns won't sort on click.  Did you base your headerCellTemplate on the default one here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/templates/ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell.html